# How to add a body to the ajax request of select 2?

Tags: drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors, jquery-select2

I would like to mimic a post to a URL with the body type of plain text (such as "select * from table") using a Select2 box, but where do i define the body that I want to post?

```
$("#sales_ids").select2({
        placeholder: "Select your Partners",
        multiple: 'multiple',
        ajax: {
            url: 'http://www.google.com/,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            multiple: 'multiple',
            allowclear: 'true',


            processResults: function p(data){

                var mapped = $.map(data, function(obj) {
                    obj.text = obj.text || obj.name;
                    obj.id = obj.id || obj.salesId;
                    return obj;



                })

                return { 
                    results: mapped
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'URL',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,

    // Data Goes Here
    data: 'select * from table'
    contentType: 'test/plain'

    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
    // Success Code
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error in Database');
    }
});
```

Comment: If I wanted the plain text "select * from table" to be within the body of the post, where is this string typed? You said 'Data goes here', Do I put data: "select * from table"?

Comment: @perry please review my edited answer. Hope that'll answer your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! I still have empty results but I got what I needed.

Comment: glad my answer helped you. please up vote if feel so.@perry